# Clicking 'discard' under an answer whilst editing a post inline causes the tags in the edit to also be removed

Tags: bug, status-completed, edits, draft

A gif to explain:

> [image]

As you can see, clicking 'discard' under an answer whilst editing a post inline causes the tags in the edit to also be removed.

I presume this is because the click handler for the 'discard' button is the same for questions and answers; if it is a question, it *does* need to delete the tags. But this doesn't work for *answers* - please can a new handler be made/or the existing one edited to check whether the discard is for a question or answer, and decide whether the tags need to be discarded or not.

---

I understand this is a rare case - but it *looks* easy to fix... if it is, please can it be fixed? :)

Comment: Curious: What are those checkboxes?

Comment: @CoolGuy they are checkboxes to add pre-defined edit reasons for easier editing - you'll find a few scripts to do this on Stack Apps. If you want this feature yourself, you could use my [SE Additional Optional Features](http://stackapps.com/q/6091/26088) userscript ;) You'll get a bunch of other features as well! :)

Comment: +1. As you stated, it is rare, but if the option is available/provided it should work properly :) Besides, rare or not, this is arguably a substantial bug, as clicking "discard" on an answer should not remove all tags on a question. Even if for Stack's sake they should look at where their scripts are being a bit rogue.

Comment: also happens on the /questions/ask page when providing an answer to your own question, but there it actually removes everything (question + answer)

Comment: @m0sa are there any plans to fix it? ;) or has the cause been found?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A fix for this is rolling out in the next build (build rev `2015.11.17.3887` on MSE/MSO, `2015.11.17.2998` on sites).

Answer (score 0):

Upon inspection of [wmd.js](http://cdn-dev.sstatic.net/js/wmd.js), it seems the bug-causing part is:

```
var tags = $('#tagnames');
if (tags.length > 0 && tags[0].func_clear) {
    tags[0].func_clear();
    tags.blur();
}
```

Now, I don't know what `func_clear()` means... but it looks like it's clearing the tags...

To fix, a simple way would be to check whether we are on an answer page or question page, and the easy way (I think) to do that would be to check whether `body` has the `question-page` class:

```
if(!$('body').hasClass('question-page')) {
    var tags = $('#tagnames');
    if (tags.length > 0 && tags[0].func_clear) {
        tags[0].func_clear();
        tags.blur();
    }
}
```

So it won't happen on question pages.

---

This is just a small inspection - there is probably a better way, and my suggestion might actually break something unintentionally...